# Tensorflow equivalent of Numpy's add.at() method

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm computing confusion matrix for a multi-label classification task. The code looks like this:

```
def compute_key_metrics(sess,X_data,y_data):
    confusion_matrix = np.zeros([n_classes,n_classes],np.int32)
    n_examples = X_data.shape[0]

    for offset in range(0,n_examples,batch_size):
    X_batch = X_data[offset:offset+batch_size]
    y_batch = y_data[offset:offset+batch_size]

    y_predicted = sess.run(tf.arg_max(logits,1),feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
    is_prediction_correct = sess.run(correct_predictions,feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
    np.add.at(confusion_matrix,[y_batch,y_predicted],is_prediction_correct.astype(np.int32))

return confusion_matrix
```

I'm using  numpy.add.at() to update the entries of the confusion matrix without explicitly looping over the predicted labels. The python implementation is quite slow. Is there a similar method in Tensorflow?

Comment: `np.add.at` is needed where the indexes repeat, and the buffered equivalent is wrong.  Yes, it is slower than the buffered version, but still faster than an explicit Python level loop.

Comment: Yes. you are right. y_batch and y_predicted will most often contain repeated  indices. That's why I'm using add.at(). I want to know if something similar can be done using some Tensorflow API.

Comment: I wonder whether a native tensorflow version would be any faster.  The numpy one is already compiled.